# Merge list elements conditionally

Tags: haskell

I'm still a newbie to haskell, but I'm trying hard to learn it. But now I came to a point, where I think I have to learn a completely new chapter of haskell.

So this is an list of lists of Int containing these numbers:

```
[[5,6,14],[1,2,9],[11,12,13],[6,13,14],[5,13,14]]
```

In the beginning all inner lists contain three numbers. The goal is to merge all overlapping lists into bigger ones:

```
[[5,6,14],[1,2,9],[11,12,13],[6,13,14],[5,13,14]]
merging elements at index 0 and 3 because of the common 6 in both lists.
[[5,6,14,13],[1,2,9],[11,12,13],[5,13,14]]
merging elements at index 0 and 2 because of the common 13 in both lists.
[[5,6,14,13,11,12],[1,2,9],[5,13,14]]
merging elements at index 0 and 2 because of the common 5,13 & 14 in both lists.
[[5,6,14,13,11,12],[1,2,9]]
```

And this should be the result of the function. The order of the lists inside the list is as irrelevant as the order of elements inside the innermost lists.

I know how to code this in any other imperative language, but here I'm stuck.

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but you should know that Haskell lists (`[a]`) are *not* arrays, but rather linked lists, and that these of course have performance characteristics that are completely different from that of arrays. If you really want arrays (probably not in this case), check out [vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector), which is pretty much the canonical choice for array these days.

Comment: It seems also that you'll be doing a lot of membership tests. Maybe you want to consider [`Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Set.html), where such checks can be done in logarithmic time.

Comment: Here's a sketch: 1) Write a function that merges two sets if they have an intersection. 2) Write a function that produces the list of all pairs of elements from two lists. 3) Pass the function from 1 over the list from 2 until it finds a pair it can do its thing with. If you ever traverse all of the list from 2 without 1 doing anything, you are done.

Comment: That's cool, Data.Set would fit perfectly in here. There is a union to combine to sets and there is intersection to check for overlapping. Nice!

Comment: Function 1 and function 2 are easy. But the third thing kills me. Also building all kind of pairs in function 2 could be an overkill as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this using `List` data structure would be like as follows. Initially write a predicate function for finding out if two list has any common elements between them:

```
hasCommon :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
hasCommon xs ys = not . null $ intersect xs ys

λ> hasCommon [1,2,3] [3]
True
λ> hasCommon [1,2,3] [4]
False
```

Now, you can implement a `solve` function which will give you your desired functionality:

```
solve :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
solve xs = case xs' of
             [] -> []
             x'@(x:[]) -> x'
             x'@(x1:x2:[]) -> x'
             x'@(x1:x2:xs) -> x1:(solve (x2:xs))
    where xs' = aux (head xs) (tail xs) []
          aux :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
          aux acc [] temp = (acc:temp)
          aux acc (y:ys) temp = if (acc `hasCommon` y)
                                then aux (union acc y) (ys ++ temp) []
                                else aux acc ys (y:temp)
```

The main part of the function is the `aux`. The function accepts three parameter. The first parameter for that function is the initial head of the input list which is used to compare it with the rest of the input list. The second parameter of the `aux` function is the `tail` of the input list. The third parameter is the temporary variable which you keep around to keep track of the elements which has been already processed. You handle two cases within the function: If the tail of the input list is empty, then you return `[acc] ++ temp` which will hold your result. That will be built up in the other case which will be described now. In the other case, you check if the head of the input list has any common elements with the head of the tail of the input list. If it has any common elements, then see how I'm passing around values to the `aux` function. Basically I populate the second input with `ys ++ temp` so that we traverse the already traversed elements. And the first parameter is the union of `xs` and `y`. The else part in that case is self-explanatory.

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> solve [[5,6,14],[1,2,9],[11,12,13],[6,13,14],[5,13,14]]
[[5,6,14,13,11,12],[1,2,9]]
λ> solve [[5,6,14],[18,19,20],[5,13,14],[1,2,9],[17,18,19],[20,21,22]]
[[5,6,14,13],[18,19,20,21,22,17],[1,2,9]]
```

Comment: Try this input: solve [[5,6,14],[18,19,20],[5,13,14],[1,2,9],[17,18,19],[20,21,22]]

Comment: @Hennes Please consider accepting Sibi's answer, if it solves your problem.